# Change the stylesheet of only the frame, not its children

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

For instance, I have a frame, and inside of the frame there is a tabWidget which contains a textBrowser, a QTableWidget, a lineEdit etc. When I change the stylesheet of the frame, for example:

```
border: 1px solid #73CDFA;
```

It changes the border of all of those items too, but I only want to change the frame's border. Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

You just have to limit the scope with

```
QFrame#frameObjName{
  border: 5px solid #73CDFA;
}
```

Here, `frameObjName` is the object name of the frame.